# Append to Firebase ref AngularFire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Let's say I'm building an infinite scroll of articles.

My article ID is passed through the URL:

```
var id = $stateParams.id;
```

I want to `startAt` that index in my Firebase collection and `limit` 10:

```
var limit = 10;
var articlesRef = new Firebase("https://example.firebaseio.com/articles").startAt(null, id).limit(limit);
$scope.articles = $firebase(articlesRef);
```

In my `loadMore()` function triggered by the *inifite-scroll* directive I want to append more:

```
  $scope.loadMore = function(){
    var limit = limit + 10;
    //Obviously this isn't going to work.
    $scope.articles = $firebase(articlesRef.startAt(null, id).limit(limit));
  }
```

- We can't *concat* because the collection being returned is an object.
- We can't use the `loaded` function more than once so we cant *concat* the `value` in the callback.

How would I **append to an existing result set** so it doesn't appear as though `articles` "*reloads*" ?

Comment: articles.push? why not that

Comment: @baba Doesn't `push` append to the remote collection?

Comment: @DanKanze This is a duplicate of the same exact question you posted a day ago and than deleted. Reason?

Comment: @Stewie My question didn't make it obvious that using `concat` on a Firebase ref wasn't possible - this became clear when you answered my previous question.

Comment: "... collection being returned is an object" - Can you show that response.

Comment: @Stewie Read the docs: http://angularfire.com/flatdoc.html#firebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky - the best way to append to a new result set is to separate out what's returned by $firebase and what's displayed in your view.

In this case, let's assume that $scope.articles is what is being displayed. The main thing is to assign the return value of $firebase() to something *other than* $scope.articles and to rely on the 'changed' event instead of 'loaded'. Then, simply copy the contents over whenever a new set needs to be loaded.

```
var articlesRef = new Firebase("https://example.firebaseio.com/articles").startAt(null, id).limit(limit);
$scope.articles = {};
var obj = $firebase(articlesRef);
obj.$on('change').function() {
  // For each property in obj, set $scope.articles.
};
```

Comment: I'm having difficulty with this solution. I have a follow up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859515/angularfire-0-5-0-on-change-event-not-firing-correctly

Comment: It's interesting this one, as I may need to implement a solution like this in a project I'm currently chipping away at, which combines Firebase with the Ionic Framework.