# AngularFire 0.5.0 $on 'change' event not firing correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Let's say I have a collection of articles I am trying to paginate through.

I'm using the `$on("change")` event to listen for changes to `index` and `limit`

```
.controller('articlesCtrl', ["$scope", "$firebase", "$stateParams", function($scope, $firebase, $stateParams) {

  var limit = 2;
  var index = $stateParams.id;
  var articlesRef = new Firebase("https://example.firebaseio.com/articles").startAt(null, index).limit(limit);
  var obj = $firebase(articlesRef);

  obj.$on("change", function() {
    var keys = obj.$getIndex();
    index = keys[keys.length-1];
    console.log(obj);
  });

  $scope.update = function(){
    limit = limit + 2;
    obj = $firebase(articlesRef.startAt(null, index).limit(limit));
  }

}]);
```

What I'm noticing - is on *initial load* the `$on("change")` event fires twice.

And *every subsequent call* to update the `index` or `limit` does not fire the `$on("change")` event.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="update();">Update</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time $scope.update fires, you assign the `obj` variable to a new reference. However, you only attach `obj.$on(change)` to the original `obj`.

This could probably be optimized with some experimentation; here's a quick brute force to get you started:

```
var limit = 2;
var index = $stateParams.id;
var articlesRef = new Firebase("https://example.firebaseio.com/articles");

$scope.update = update;
update(); // initialize

function update(){
   limit = limit + 2;
   var obj = $firebase(articlesRef.startAt(null, index).limit(limit));
   obj.$on("loaded", function() {
      var keys = obj.$getIndex();
      index = keys[keys.length-1];
      console.log(obj);
   });
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason AngularFire doesn't attach the `$on('change')` event to the new reference? That seems silly to me if you are using the same variable name and scope.

Comment: It's an entirely different javascript reference--`obj` now points to a new place in memory, a new variable allocation--there's no way to reference the old one, to know you've wiped the memory location, or to link the two together. Is there something wrong with the approach I've offered? It's a much cleaner scope and less bug-prone way to organize, besides working according to the use case you've provided.

Comment: Oh I wasn't speaking to you solution I was speaking to AngularFire. I meant that if you update the value of the ref I feel like `$on('change')` event should fire. I feel like AngularFire should bind the updated ref to the old object if you are explicitly redeclaring its new value like in this example. Just thinking out loud.

Comment: The obj in question is not changed because you create a new $firebase instance and apply limit() or startAt() to it. It still contains the same, unchanged data. Your new object is changed, but in no way modifies or interacts with the old object. Since you've erased the reference to it, by replacing `obj` with a new pointer, there is no way they could interact or talk to one another anyways, even if this were logical. I think once you understand all the components involved, you'll see that this would be undesirable as well as technically impossible.

Comment: I see what you are saying now. For some reason I was thinking `$on` behaved similarly to `$watch` but now I realize `$on` isn't an observer that takes an argument, it's actually a property of the object itself.

Comment: Hey Dan Kanze, can you create a fiddle/plnkr for me because I am facing the same problem.